# Below is a code to determine which process launched the application. This code works only 10% of the time. Remaining 90%, GDI+ Access Violation Error

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.8

```
private string parentProcessName()
{
    var processId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
    var queryFromId = string.Format("SELECT ParentProcessId FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = {0}", processId);
    var searchById = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", queryFromId);
    var idResults = searchById.Get().GetEnumerator(); //
    idResults.MoveNext();
    var queryObject = idResults.Current;
    var parentId = (uint)queryObject["ParentProcessId"];
    var parent = Process.GetProcessById((int)parentId);
    string parentFinal = parent.ProcessName;

    return parentFinal;
}
```

The exception is thrown at the line with "//" at the end. How can I make this code run everytime?

Comment: Have you looked in the event log for any clues as to why WMI is doing this? Does this happen on multiple PCs or just one?

Answer (score 0):

According to e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobjectsearcher.get?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0 you should be able to just loop over the result of `.Get()`; since you want the first item, you can just `return` from that loop:

```
private string parentProcessName()
{
    var processId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
    var queryFromId = string.Format("SELECT ParentProcessId FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = {0}", processId);
    foreach (var queryObject in new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", queryFromId).Get())
    {
        var parentId = (uint)queryObject["ParentProcessId"];
        var parent = Process.GetProcessById((int)parentId);
        return parent.ProcessName;
    }
    throw new Exception("No parent process found");
}
```